# Why my databinding does not work with HashMap?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have such layout variable:

```
<variable
name="string"
type="....UtilsClass" />
```

then I would like to get access to this class HashMap and get item by key:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:title="@{string.strings.get(9167)}"
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

but when the app runs I don't see any string in the toolbar. On the other hand when I would like to set this string directly from activity I manage to do it. Why does it happen and how I can solve this problem? Or it is totally impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find very good solution. We have such variable:

```
<data>
  <import type="java.util.HashMap"/>
  <variable name="map" type="HashMap&lt;Integer,String&gt;"/>
</data>
```

in fragment/activity set data for this variable:

```
viewBinding!!.map = our map
```

and get data for example in TextView:

```
android:text="@{map.get(11080)}"
```

examples of setting some other types of data:

```
<import type="java.util.Map"/>
<import type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
<variable name="list" type="ArrayList&lt;String&gt;"/>
<variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String,String&gt;"/>
<variable name="arrays" type="String[]"/>
```

useful [link](https://programmersought.com/article/63065738443/)